# Jaxb2Marshaller Mock Bean coming as null JUNIT5

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit5

I am trying to write JUNIT for a method . Am able to mock all other beans except Jaxb2Marshaller. In actual method i am getting null pointer exception for Jaxb2Marshaller. Other beans are available from the same configuration class. Why only Jaxb2Marshaller bean is not available.

**TEST CLASS**

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class EPSGCFundAndActivateAPIClientTest {

    @Autowired
    EPSGCFundAndActivateAPIClient epsgcFundAndActivateAPIClient;

    @MockBean
    @Qualifier("paymentServiceRestTemplate")
    RestTemplate paymentServiceRestTemplate;

    @MockBean
    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller;

    @Test
    void consume() throws JAXBException {
        String input = ""; 
        //I cannot mock the jaxb2Marshaller marshal call . Because its void.
        epsgcFundAndActivateAPIClient.consume(input);
    }

}
```

**CONFIGURATION CLASS**

```java
@Configuration
@DependsOn({"otsProperties"})
public class BeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(properties);
        return marshaller;
    }
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate paymentServiceRestTemplate() {
        final RestTemplateBuilder builder =
                new RestTemplateBuilder().basicAuthentication("ABC", "123456");
        builder.messageConverters(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
        return builder.build();
    }

}
```

**ACTUAL CLASS**

```java
@Component("epsGCFundAndActivateAPIClient")
public class EPSGCFundAndActivateAPIClient  {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("paymentServiceRestTemplate")
    RestTemplate paymentServiceRestTemplate;

    @Autowired
    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller;

    @Override
    public PaymentServiceResponse consume(Input input) {
      StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        jaxb2Marshaller.createMarshaller().marshal(input.getPayload(),sw); // Getting null pointer Exception for jaxb2Marshaller

        paymentServiceRestTemplate.methodCall(sw); // If i comment out the above line this method is getting called successfully. Means paymentServiceRestTemplate is available.

    } 
}
```

Comment: In-case it helps anyone, I didn't need to mock the Jaxb2Marshaller, I just needed to add the class where my bean was defined to the context configuration on my test class:   

e.g. @ContextConfiguration(classes = {..., Jaxb2Configuration.class})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you get a `NullPointerException` beacuse `jaxb2Marshaller` is null, but rather because the expression `jaxb2Marshaller.createMarshaller()` returned null, and the further call to `marshal` is the one to actual throw the exception.

If that is indeed the case, it happens because you did not mock the call to `createMarshaller`. you have to mock `jaxb2Marshaller.createMarshaller()` to return a marshaller:

```java
@Test
void consume() throws JAXBException {
    when(jaxb2Marshaller.createMarshaller()).thenReturn(whateverYouNeed);

    String input = ""; 
    //I cannot mock the jaxb2Marshaller marshal call . Because its void.
    epsgcFundAndActivateAPIClient.consume(input);

}
```

Comment: Thanks , That was the problem.